# Using an If statement in PHP but not working

Tags: php, if-statement

[image]

What I want to do is When I enter all my information (for client ID 199 in the picture) In my account being submit it, it goes into the database. BUT I want it to change to something and so i **added an if statement**

Here the code im adding to the existing code already at the BOTTOM of the code

```
if ($vpr_clid == 199) {
        $vpr_cl_name = "Shelley Madsen And Associates";
      }
```

if the ($vpr_clid = 199) 
i want the clname to be "Shelley Madsen And Associates" then what is show in the table below instead of "Nice and White Smiles" (that an example of the results look like)

but when i chcek the database it not changing it and still show "Nice and White Smiles :(

I dont see any error, so it might be the placement of the code i have to put the IF statement in the huge php file? Dont know how to fix this issue

Thanks (the code below is the base code before i added the If statement)
I also insert the if statement before the function were called but still didnt work example

```
if ($vpr_clid == 199) {
            $vpr_cl_name = "Shelley Madsen And Associates";
          }

  $result = InsertIntoPayReminder($link, $vars);
  $result = GetVpr_Id($link, $vars);
```

[image]

```
<?php 
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['company'] != "ACB") {    
         // redirect to the logout page
       $redirect = 'logout.php';
       include  './includes/redirect.php';
    }

class variables_obj {
    var $vpr_plan = '';
    var $vpr_id = '';
    var $vpr_clid = '';
    var $vpr_cl_name = '';
    var $vpr_cl_phone = '';
    var $vpr_call_start_date = '';

    var $vpr_db_account = '';

    var $vpr_db_fname = '';
    var $vpr_db_mname = '';
    var $vpr_db_lname = '';

    var $vpr_rp_fname = '';
    var $vpr_rp_mname = '';  
    var $vpr_rp_lname = ''; 

    var $vpr_rp_address = '';
    var $vpr_rp_city = '';
    var $vpr_rp_state = '';
    var $vpr_rp_zipcode = '';

    var $vpr_rp_phonenum = '';
    var $vpr_rp_phonetype = '';

    var $vpr_date_entered = '';
    var $newrecdt = '';

    var $vpl_day_offset = '';
    var $vpl_action = '';       

    var $vpr_promocode = '';

}
function ScrubPhone($old_phone_num) {
    $phone_length = strlen($old_phone_num);
    $new_phone_num = "";

    for($i = 0; $i < $phone_length; $i = $i + 1) {
        if(is_numeric($old_phone_num[$i])) {
            $new_phone_num .= $old_phone_num[$i];
        }
    }
    return $new_phone_num;
}

function ScheduleCreated($link, $vars) {

    $query = "UPDATE v_payreminder SET vpr_schedule_created = '1' WHERE vpr_id='".$vars->vpr_id."'";

    if (!mysql_query($query,$link)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    return true;    
}


function CreateScheduleRow($link, $vars){

//  echo "vpl_day_offset: ".$vars->vpl_day_offset."<br>";
//  echo "vpl_action: ".$vars->vpl_action."<br>";

    $plus_days = " +".$vars->vpl_day_offset." days";

//  echo "plus days: ".$plus_days."<br>";

    $date_offset = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($vars->vpr_date_entered)).$plus_days);
    $date_offset = date("Y-m-d", $date_offset);
//  echo "date_offset: ".$date_offset."<br>";


//  $date_offset = strtotime(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($vars->vpr_date_entered))." +".$vars->vpl_day_offset." days");
//  $date_offset = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 day");  

//  echo "date_offset: ".$date_offset."<br>";   

    $query = "INSERT INTO   v_pr_schedule (
                                    vpr_id, 
                                    vsc_plan, 
                                    vsc_date_entered, 
                                    vsc_action, 
                                    vsc_action_date, 
                                    vsc_status
                                    ) VALUES (
                                    '$vars->vpr_id',
                                    '$vars->vpr_plan',
                                    '$vars->vpr_date_entered',
                                    '$vars->vpl_action',
                                    '$date_offset',
                                    'VACT')";

//echo "query: ".$query."<br>"; 

    if (!mysql_query($query,$link)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    return true;    
}

function CreateSchedule($link, &$vars) {
//  CREATE SCHEDULE

    $query = "  SELECT  vpl_day_offset, vpl_action, vpl_condition 
                    FROM        v_plan 
                    WHERE       vpl_plan = '".$vars->vpr_plan."'"; 

//  echo "query: ".$query."<br>";

    $qresult = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$qresult) {
        print(mysql_error());
    }

    if ($qresult && mysql_num_rows($qresult) > 0 ) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qresult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $vars->vpl_day_offset = $row['vpl_day_offset'];
            $vars->vpl_action = $row['vpl_action'];
            if ($row['vpl_condition'] == 'OO') {        
                CreateScheduleRow($link, $vars);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function InsertIntoPayReminder($link, &$vars) {     

$vars->vpr_cl_name = strtr($vars->vpr_cl_name, "'", " ");

//echo "Client Name: ".$vars->vpr_cl_name."<br><br>";
//exit();

    $sql="INSERT INTO v_payreminder (
                            vpr_clid,
                            vpr_cl_name,
                            vpr_cl_phone,
                            vpr_call_start_date,
                            vpr_db_account,
                            vpr_db_fname,
                            vpr_db_mname,
                            vpr_db_lname,
                            vpr_rp_fname,
                            vpr_rp_mname,
                            vpr_rp_lname,
                            vpr_rp_phonenum,
                            vpr_rp_phonetype,
                            vpr_rp_address,
                            vpr_rp_city,
                            vpr_rp_state,
                            vpr_rp_zipcode,
                            vpr_promo,
                            vpr_date_entered) VALUES (
                            '$vars->vpr_clid', 
                            '$vars->vpr_cl_name',
                            '$vars->vpr_cl_phone',
                            '$vars->vpr_call_start_date',
                            '$vars->vpr_db_account',
                            '$vars->vpr_db_fname',
                            '$vars->vpr_db_mname',
                            '$vars->vpr_db_lname',
                            '$vars->vpr_rp_fname',
                            '$vars->vpr_rp_mname',
                            '$vars->vpr_rp_lname',
                            '$vars->vpr_rp_phonenum',
                            '$vars->vpr_rp_phonetype',
                            '$vars->vpr_rp_address',
                            '$vars->vpr_rp_city',
                            '$vars->vpr_rp_state',
                            '$vars->vpr_rp_zipcode',
                            '$vars->vpr_promocode',
                            '$vars->vpr_date_entered')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$link)) {
        die('Error2: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    return true;
}

function GetVpr_Id($link, &$vars) {

    // Find out what vpr_id is
    $query = "SELECT vpr_id FROM v_payreminder ";
    $query .= "WHERE vpr_clid = '".$vars->vpr_clid."' AND vpr_date_entered = '".$vars->vpr_date_entered."'";

    $qresult = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$qresult) {
        print(mysql_error());
    }

    if ($qresult && mysql_num_rows($qresult) > 0 ) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($qresult, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        $vars->vpr_id = $row['vpr_id'];
    }
}

function InsertInActivity($link, $vars) {
// ENTER INTO ACTIVITY

    $vaction_desc = 'PATIENT ENTERED';

     $sql = "INSERT INTO    v_pr_activity (
                                    vpr_id, 
                                    va_plan, 
                                    va_action_dttm, 
                                    va_action_code, 
                                    va_action_desc,
                                va_disposition_code,
                                    va_disposition_desc,
                                    va_status_code,
                                va_status_desc 
                                    ) VALUES (
                                    '$vars->vpr_id',
                                    '$vars->vpr_plan',
                                    '$vars->vpr_date_entered',
                                'VINIT',
                                    '$vaction_desc', 
                                    'SUCCESS',
                                    'SUCCESS',
                                    'VACT',
                                    'ACTIVE' 
                                    )";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$link)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

}

include './includes/dblogin.php';

$vars = new variables_obj(); 

    $vars->vpr_plan = 'VP01';
    $vars->vpr_clid = $_SESSION['userid'];


//-------------------------------------------------------
// No commas can be in client name or they will
// mess up the Global Connect CSV file.
//-------------------------------------------------------
    $vpr_cl_name = $_SESSION['username'];
    $vpr_cl_name = str_replace(",", " ", $vpr_cl_name);

    $vars->vpr_cl_name = $vpr_cl_name;      
//-------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------------------------------

    $vars->vpr_cl_phone = ScrubPhone($_SESSION['uphone']);
    $vars->vpr_call_start_date = '0000-00-00';

    $vars->vpr_db_account = $_POST['ndaccnum'];

    $vars->vpr_db_fname = $_POST['ndfreqname'];
    $vars->vpr_db_mname = $_POST['ndmname'];
    $vars->vpr_db_lname = $_POST['ndlreqname'];

    $vars->vpr_rp_fname = $_POST['ndrfreqname'];
    $vars->vpr_rp_mname = $_POST['ndrmname'];  
    $vars->vpr_rp_lname = $_POST['ndrlreqname']; 

    $vars->vpr_rp_address = '';
    $vars->vpr_rp_city = '';
    $vars->vpr_rp_state = $_POST['ndrstatereqname'];
    $vars->vpr_rp_zipcode = $_POST['ndrreqzipcode'];

    $phonenumber = $_POST['1ndrreqphone'].$_POST['2ndrreqphone'].$_POST['3ndrreqphone'];

    $vars->vpr_rp_phonenum = $phonenumber;
    $vars->vpr_rp_phonetype = $_POST['treqphone'];

    $vars->vpr_date_entered = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $vars->newrecdt = date('Ymd');

    $vars->vpr_promocode = $_POST['promocode'];


//  echo "vpr_plan: ".$vars->vpr_plan."<br>";
//  echo "vpr_date_entered: ".$vars->vpr_date_entered."<br>";
//  echo "newrecdt: ".$vars->newrecdt."<br>";
//  echo "vpr_clid: ".$vars->vpr_clid."<br>";
//  echo "vpr_id: ".$vars->vpr_id."<br>";

    $result = InsertIntoPayReminder($link, $vars);
    $result = GetVpr_Id($link, $vars);
    $result = InsertInActivity($link, $vars);
    $result = CreateSchedule($link, $vars); 
    $result = ScheduleCreated($link, $vars);

//  echo "vpr_id: ".$vars->vpr_id."<br>";

    mysql_close($link);     

 // redirect       
   $redirect = 'vpayremind.php';   
    include  './includes/redirect.php';
?>
```

Comment: You said you put the if statement at the bottom? I believe you would need to either create a new function function to check the $vpr_clid and change the cl_name before calling the InsertIntoActivity or put the if statement at the top of the InsertIntoPayActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay referencing the following lines..

```
if ( $vpr_clid == 199 ) {

    $vpr_cl_name = "Shelley Madsen And Associates";
}

$result = InsertIntoPayReminder($link, $vars);


...and then:

function InsertIntoPayReminder($link, &$vars) {     

    $vars->vpr_cl_name = strtr($vars->vpr_cl_name, "'", " ");

so on and so forth... }
```

it doesnt seem as if you are actually setting the value of the class object. You seem to be setting some arbitrary php variable to the name you want, and then passing a totally different ' $vars ' object into the function. I don't see any reason to believe that the ' $vars ' you are passing into the function call contains the name value you want it to contain. You should be assigning the value of ' $vars ' before passing it in.

For instance:

```
if ( $vpr_clid == 199 ) {

    $vars[ 'vpr_cl_name' ] = "Shelley Madsen And Associates";
}
```

then you can get rid of this line all together:

```
$vars->vpr_cl_name = strtr($vars->vpr_cl_name, "'", " ");
```